# Cannot update value using findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the mongodb document that I want to update through mongoose:

[image]

My model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const reservationSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  timeStart: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  timeEnd: {
    //NOT REQUIRED
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  venue: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  seat: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Reservation", reservationSchema);
```

Using the findOneAndUpdate function, I am trying to find one document in the reservations collection by username and timeEnd, such that username is P19010770 and timeEnd should be an empty string.

Then, I want to update the timeEnd with the value passed in the req.body. But my timeEnd does not get update using the following code (it's still an empty string...)

Code to update (does not work):
[image]

This is where username and timeEnd values are passed from:
[image]

I've spent hours trying to find the problem but I still could not get what went wrong. Please help!

**UPDATE:**
I tried to directly find the document using `{ _id: "64a82c5fc8b7aa7823d82a34" }`, and timeEnd got successfully updated... so this means that there is something wrong with the filter part..?

Comment: Just before `findOneAndUpdate`, what is the output of `console.log(username)` and `console.log(timeEnd)`?  Should you handle the possibility that `"timeEnd"` may not exist in the document?

Comment: @rickhg12hs omg! username is **undefined**, timeEnd is **23:27**. But when I consoled log the studentData.username before fetch (refer to the last img, it was printing `see what is this: P19010770`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs nope, even though timeEnd is not required in model, it will always exist as "" when the reservation document is first created.

Comment: So you know what needs to be fixed - cool!  BTW, please don't use images for code/error messages/stack traces/tracebacks/etc. - just paste the text into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

**findOneAndUpdate()** takes 4 arguments in which two are necessary and 2 are optinal.
Where **filter** and **update** are must be specified.
while two other args are **options** and **callback**.

Where filter gives the first document with the given criteria and it updates that document with given update data.

All your logic and code are correct but you do not have to use $set while using findOneAndUpdate(). Mongoose automatically updates the attribute of document with given update query.

Checkout this documentation of mongoose [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

So, your code will be

```
Reservation.findOneAndUpdate(
  {username: username, timeEnd: ""},
  {timeEnd: timeEnd}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is syntatically is correct,
but their is possiblility that in you database there are many records with same username and empty timeEnd
so it is updated another record
you can use below code for now this will also work
and pass option true to get update record in same db call for updated record

```
let data = await Reservation.findOneAndUpdate(
 {username: username, timeEnd: ""},
 {$set:{timeEnd: timeEnd}},
 {new: true}
);
$set will also work
or you can pass value directly
{ timeEnd: timeEnd}
or you can use updateOn function also with same structure above
let data = await Reservation.updateOn(
 {username: username, timeEnd: ""},
 {timeEnd: timeEnd},
 {new: true}
);
```